# What additional ethics you find in Buddhism which are not found in other religions?

Tags: theravada

What additional ethics you find in Buddhism which are not found in other religions?
Other religions mean Abrahamic religions, Hinduism, Taoism or any other religion you know.
I also like to know whether other religions have any ethics you do not find in Buddhism.
To start with concentrate on five, eight precepts compare them to other religions.

Answer (score 4):

### Divisive Speech.

This is definitely something unique to Buddhism (I think). Other religions talk about lying, but I don't remember any mentions of divisive speech.

> Abandoning divisive speech he abstains from divisive speech. What he has heard here he does not tell there to break those people apart from these people here. What he has heard there he does not tell here to break these people apart from those people there. Thus reconciling those who have broken apart or cementing those who are united, he loves concord, delights in concord, enjoys concord, speaks things that create concord.

This comes from Buddha's special insight into the nature of *dukkha*. Dukkha comes from a conflict of mind, an unresolvable uninergated contradiction. Craving is one example of such contradiction, aversion is another, and conflict between people because of their incompatible *views* (about the world or about each other) is a third!

So when you engage in divisive speech, you create and spread conflict between the sides, which will sooner or later bear the fruit of dukkha.

While the non-violence is taught by many religions, it is only (to my limited knowledge) in Buddhism is where the source of dukkha is understood so deeply that the role of divisive speech in creating dukkha is clearly recognized.

### Harsh speech

> They give up harsh speech. They speak in a way that’s mellow, pleasing to the ear, lovely, going to the heart, polite, likable and agreeable to the people.

Answer (score 1):

Very high level comparison, not intended to be perfect but at least highlight known ethical differences:

**Before Life:**

Buddhism - Ignorance

Taoism - Just reincarnation, no specific explanation on ignorance

Abrahamic - Original Sin

**During life:**

Buddhism - You are the owner of your Karma, good/bad things happen because of your actions.

Taoism - Follow the "Path", be conscious of good and bad, cause and effect. Also believe in karma, but not as much explanation as Buddhism. Follows the Master's teachings.

Abrahamic - Good/bad things happen due to God's plan

**After Life:**

Buddhism - Eliminate Ignorance, Escape reincarnation, through Eight Folds Paths

Taoism - Reincarnation. Believe in Ghosts and Deities. Worships Deities and Ancestors.

Abrahamic - Enjoy life in heaven with God, 'Believing in God' is the only path to rise to Heaven

**Salvation:**

Buddhism - no one can save you, except Yourself. Practice the 8-folds path. Meditation is Key.

Taoism - Specific ceremonies to help the ghosts reincarnate. Possible to ascend as deities. Lot's of techniques and chanting to make life better/wealthier. Communicate with ghostly beings, fang shui designs, palm/face/birthday readings. Meditation is optional.

Abrahamic - no one can save you, except God. Meditation not preferred, some suggests may attract "demons".

**Path to Wisdom:**

Buddhism - Understand the true nature of suffering, eliminate suffering. Everything that is conditioned are impermanent, suffering, and no fixed self/identity.

Taoism - Be a good person. Be mindful of Karma. Follows the right Path according to master's teachings.

Abrahamic - Believe in God is wisdom. Happiness can be eternal as long as in Heaven. God is permanent. Soul is true self and permanent.

Comment: "Follow the law, not the person" in the Nirvana Sutra accords with the points under "Salvation" and "Path to Wisdom".

Answer (score 1):

Other religions, as far as seen, may have certain elements of generosity, yet mostly upwardly, like in arabic.

Most religion praise the worthy and honor of parents.

Many religions have similar precepts like the basic five, yet mostly limited toward human beings to keep, some only toward "own kind". No other religion has a simple and clear cut set of the basic precepts.

Most, especially Arabic religions, praise abstain from sensuality, sex, intoxication, entertainment... most more than the basic four.

Certain Dhammic religions do not give much into abstain from sensuality.

Like in Dhamma, most religions have the unspoken precept of refuge as obligation, even stronger.

Less religions, here mostly the Dhammic, have focus on mental cultivation as guided teaching.

Liberation from the bounds of becoming is only found in the Buddhas teachings.

It's all naturally: no giving up outwardly, no complete virtue, no real virtue, no concentration, no concentration, no wisdom, no liberation.

As far as such as re-ligion can still be found, it's probably only the Buddhas which has been not become solvely secular missing contemplatives and homeless life totally.

Generally my person does not encourage to waste time, since even the best rest disappears very fast and anicent paths will be soon no more traceable since no one has gone them any more.

There is a nice and friendly "[all religions community](https://www.religiousforums.com/forums/)", my person got known this days. Surely a good place if interested to explore, Nyom Sarath.

*(not given for trade and exchange but for release)*

Answer (score 1):

The Vinaya, including the four parajikas (defeats).

Answer (score 0):

well the short answer is that right view is not found in wrong doctrines and since it is the view and samadhi and dana which determine the realms of rebirth, people who cling to their wrong views and yet are skilled into the jhanas may or may not access some realms of rebirths. It turns out that most devas and humans who behave well have access to plenty of realms, but the buddhas claims that there is a realm only accessible to non-returners and above. https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sagga/loka.html

The thing is that you would like a list of meritorious cetana-actions or a list of precepts which are not found in wrong doctrines, but all there is samadhi either tainted by some wrong view or tainted by right view. So concretely it is the same word & the same jhana, but the intention changes and, as per the claim of the buddha that the cetana of an activity is the karma of this activity, the result changes.
So the people who create wrong views and yet are skilled into jhanas do not know about this ''additional ethics'', but only because they do not have right view and it is right view which is really this ''additional ethics''.

Comment: Right view is not considered ethics. It is considered wisdom.

Answer (score 0):

Abortion.  Buddhism is the only major religion to explicitly ban abortion in its foundational texts.  Moreover, it condemns all parties involved in the act including the doctor and anyone who provides aid in the procurement of the procedure.

It's found in the Vinaya - https://en.dhammadana.org/sangha/vinaya/227/4pk.htm